# For what is css.php in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

In webroot i found a file called css.php. Can someone tell me why is this used for.
I have no clue what is this used for i did check the .htacess and that too didn't give me any clue.

Comment: have you had a look inside the `css.php` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for combining your CSS files into one downloadable file for the user. That reduces http requests and speeds up the page load. Read here:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/morrislaptop/2008/06/23/combine-your-js-css-files-for-faster-loading